# How to store randomly generated lists in python

Tags: python, save, output

I am a mathematician with limited programming experience, but am building a neural network to generate curves with certain properties. I've built a training set which looks like a list of 1000 randomly generated numbers between -1 and 1 as follows:

```
import random

N = 1000     # Number of points in training set
Training_set = []
for i in range(N):
     Training_set.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
```

This works just fine, but I'd like to save the list Training_set so that I can modify the script and see how the resulting cost function changes **with respect to the same training set.** Currently, a new training set is generated every time I run the script. I tried writing the above code in a separate python file and importing it to the file where I'm running analysis on the neural network, but to my dismay, a new training set is generated every time even with imports. Copy-pasting is the simplest option in terms of saving randomly generated data, but with such a large list, that seems a bit ridiculous to me (especially if I want to keep scaling up N).

How can I save the data generated in one file somewhere else in a way that it can be called upon again later? This seems like a fairly basic and fundamental thing, I'm sure there's a lot of references out there that address this, but I didn't even know how to search for it. So if someone can point me in the right direction (either explicitly or with a reference), it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Save it in a file using `json` or `pickle`.

Comment: What's wrong with using a fixed seed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the same values everytime you run the program, you can use random.seed.

```
import random
random.seed(1) # can be any positive int value

N = 1000     # Number of points in training set
Training_set = []
for i in range(N):
     Training_set.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
```

Another option is to export your data to a .csv or .txt, for example, and then read from the file.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't know how to choose the seed for the random number generator. That's definitely the simplest way, as I have no idea how to export data or make python read csv or txt files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a mathematician I suggest you can familiar with [numpy](https://numpy.org/) which will help you overcome many of python's in-built functions limitations. Using numpy you can try:

```
import numpy as np

np.savetxt('test.out', np.random.uniform(-1,1,1000), delimiter=',')
```

`np.savetxt` allows to save the output of 1000 random `np.random.uniform()` samples between -1 and 1

Edit: After re-reading your question, indeed it is more important to set a seed rather than freezing your data.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to write to a text file so you can compare view and compare the values, and you can also read it back into the code.

```
import random

N = 1000     # Number of points in training set
Training_set = []
for i in range(N):
    Training_set.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))

# Write new values to a text file
with open('Training_set.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writelines(f"{Training_set}\n")

# read from a text file
with open('Training_set.txt', 'r') as f:
    training_set_output = f.readlines()
    print(training_set_output)
```